# PhoneGap app doesn't query the server two times in a row

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova

Here's the situation:

I have a PhoneGap app and a Tomcat server. The app queries the server for some data via $.ajax POST call and displays it.

The first time I try to peform the query pressing some button I have on my app UI all goes well, what happens is, if I try the same thing for the second time, the server doesn't get the query and the app displays the same data it did the last time. Looks like it's catching the data in the in-app browser...

Any ideas how to make the app actually query the server EVERY time?

Thank you very much!

EDIT: Here's the code I have

PhoneGap code:

```
function showDialog() {
    var sessionid = window.localStorage.getItem("sessionid");
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://192.168.7.56:8443/Mobile_Signature/service/pdf-signature",
        data: { action : "get-txcertificates" , sessionid : sessionid },
        success: function(result) {
                    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
                    CertificatesDialog.show(function() {}, function() {alert("some error");}, JSON.parse(result));
                 }
    });
}
```

And here is the servlet code which receives the POST query and only gets called the first time:

```
if (request.getParameter("action").equals("get-txcertificates")) {

    System.out.println("Obtaining certificates");
String user = DataController.getInstance().getUserID(sessionid);
    String access_token = DataController.getInstance()
                .getTxAccessToken(sessionid);
try {
    System.out.println("getting certificates with user " + user
            + " and accesstoken: " + access_token);
    X509Certificate[] certs = ServiceFactory.getServiceWrapper(
            ServiceFactory.SW_SERVICE).getUserCertificates(user,
                    access_token);

    JSONArray certsArray = new JSONArray();
    for (X509Certificate c : certs) {
    System.out.println("dn: " + c.getSubjectDN().toString());
    certsArray.put(c.getSubjectDN().toString());
    }
    response.getWriter().print(certsArray);

    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | MessageNotAuthenticatedException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Please post the code you have.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Code posted!

Comment: Is this on iOS 6.x by any chance? Apparently, iOS 6 is caching POST requests. http://arstechnica.com/apple/2012/09/developers-claim-safari-in-ios-6-breaks-web-apps-with-aggressive-caching/

Comment: Yep.. it's the last version of iOS. Is there any way to clear that cache? Using javascript if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a dummy solution to avoid caching in POST requests in iOS 6:

Generate a random number and add it as a parameter to your request. Something like this:

```
var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*1001);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://yoururl/yourservice",
    data: { foo : "bar" , nocaching : randomnumber },
    success: successCallback
});
```

By adding the randomnumber parameter every POST request looks different to the browser so it's not caching it anymore. No matter the server doesn't read it.

Hope this helps to someone.